# Ordenar consulta MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sql

Ahora mismo tengo la siguiente consulta de MongoDB a través de Mongoose:

```
var g = new RegExp(search, 'i');
var query = { $or: [ {Tit: g}, {Resumen: g} ] };

Book.find(query).exec((err, books) => {
    if(err) {
        res.status(500).send({message: "Error en la petición"});
    } else {
        res.status(200).send({books});
    }
});
```

La consulta me permite obtener los libros que contengan en el título o resumen la cadena almacenada en query. Me gustaría poder ordenarlos de tal manera que primero aparecieran los resultados donde dicha cadena estuviera en el título y luego los que sólo apareciera en el resumen.

Comment: ¿y por qué no haces dos búsquedas y las concatenas?

Comment: es otra opción, pero serían 2 consultas y por ende más lento no?

Comment: Cada una individual imagino que tardaria menos que las dos juntas ... pero vaya, es lo que se me ocurre. No se como hacer lo que pides con una consulta.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.find(query).sort({"campo":-1}).exec...
```

- `-1`: si es descendente
- `1`: si es ascendete